# MongoDB find repeteated values in an array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Say I have a collection with documents like—

```
{
    'name': 'Hawaiian',
    'toppings': ['ham', 'cheese', 'pineapple'],
}
```

Or—

```
{
    'name': 'Peperonni',
    'toppings': ['cheese', 'pepperoni'],
}
```

How can I get a list of all `topping`s that appear in more than one document? So, for the two documents above, it'd be `cheese`.

Ideally as "close" to the database as possible—I know I can get a list of all toppings with `distinct`, then loop through all documents at the application level, but that'd be too expensive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Though a long query, but you can take a look.
This is the aggregation framework with mongodb 2.2

```
db.test2.aggregate({$project:{"toppings":1, "_id":0}}, {$unwind:"$toppings"}, {$group:{"_id":"$toppings", count:{$sum:1}}}, {$match:{count:{$gt:1}}}, {$project:{"_id":1}})

{ "result" : [ { "_id" : "cheese" } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

Explain my query step:

1. Only want the `toppings` field
2. Expand all the values in `toppings`
3. Group by values in `toppings` and count the number
4. Find the number of the value which bigger than 1
5. Get only value(toppings), `count` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would get the list of all toppings, and then check for

```
db.coll.find({"topping": topping}).count() > 1
```

Note that I tried this in the mongo shell, and while the pymongo syntax would be exactly the same, I'm not sure where the count is implemented - in pymongo or in the database.

[EDIT]

pymongo seems to delegate the count() to mongodb, so that instead of a full query, the count operation is performed by the database.

Comment: I'm assuming that's within a loop looping over all `toppings`—in my case the list of pizzas and toppings is ridiculously long—it takes too long to calculate. I was hoping this could be done in the DB (MapReduce, perhaps?)

Comment: oh then go for the aggregation framework. There's one answer posted - I've heard a lot about its efficiency, but have never tried it seriously :)